# Any Fixes For ImGui AddRect

Tags: c++

```
ImGui::GetWindowDrawList()->AddRect(ImVec2(ModelEspInfo[i].pOutX, ModelEspInfo[i].pOutY), 5750 / ModelEspInfo[i].RealDistance, IM_COL32(245, 110, 110, 255), 12, 2.0f);
```

> Error: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "float" to "ImVec2"

Answer (score 1):

Please, format your question and add some context.

The declaration of `addRect` looks like this:

```
IMGUI_API void  AddRect(const ImVec2& p_min, const ImVec2& p_max, ImU32 col, float rounding = 0.0f, ImDrawCornerFlags rounding_corners = ImDrawCornerFlags_All, float thickness = 1.0f);
```

Without more context to your example I can only guess what you are trying to do. Check your parameters. You only have 5, `addRect` takes six (although two are optional, but it looks like you want the thickness to be 2, so you need all six). You definitly need a `ImVec` as second parameter.